# angular.Scope.Event.stopPropagation not present

Tags: angularjs

In testing my app with Jasmine/Karma, I noticed some interesting behavior when handling scope events:

```
$scope.$on('some-event', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then in my test I broadcasted the event from the `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('some-event');
```

This resulted in a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function
at null.<anonymous>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `stopPropagation` is only available for events created via `scope.$emit`, not `scope.$broadcast`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on):

> `stopPropagation` - {`function=`}: calling `stopPropagation` function will cancel further event propagation **(available only for events that were `$emit`-ed).**